# The Name 'data' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I am trying to generate a try catch method in a class, But I am facing this error message, Please help me to solve this.
My class is

```
public string Countryadd(string country, string id)
{

     try
     {
         string data="0";
         string qry1 = "select Country from Country where Country='" + country + "'";//Checking weather txtcountry(Country Name) value is already exixst or not. If exist return 1 and not exists go to else condition
         SqlDataReader dr = conn.query(qry1);
         if (dr.Read())
         {
             return data = "1";
         }
         else//If Country Name Not Exists
         {
             string qry = "insert into Country values('" + id + "','" + country + "')";//Insertin data into database Table Country
             conn.nonquery(qry);
         }

     }
     catch (Exception Ex)
     {
         ShowPopUpMsg(Ex.Message);
     }
     return data;
 }
```

Comment: Move `string data="0";` just before the `try` block. You are defining the `data` variable inside the `try` block. This means that it's only accessible inside that code block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you define your `data` variable in *try* block, it doesn't seems outside of this blocks. It is only available in try block and any child scope.

You can move it's definition outside of your *try-catch* block.

```
string data="0";
try
{
   ...
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
     ShowPopUpMsg(Ex.Message);
}
return data;
```

Read: [3.7 Scopes (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) from MSDN

Answer (score 5):

You need to put the definition of data before the `try` block:

```
   string data="0";

   try {
```

The `{}` brackets define the scope of a variable.

You can only access a variable within that scope.

Answer (score 2):

`data` is currently defined within the scope of the `try` block, you need to move it outside

```
string data = "0";
try
{
...
}
catch(NullReferenceException ex)
{
}
catch(SomethingRelatedToDataReaderException ex)
{
}
return data;
```

Also, you shouldn't really try to catch `Exception`, you should try to catch the specific types of exceptions. This helps to avoid covering up issues as well as giving you more control

Comment: How can i catch that specific types of exceptions?

Comment: @SemilSebastian - I've updated my code snippet to demonstrate. Also, even though I appreciate the accepted answer I think that Soner's answer should be the accepted one since it includes links to the documentation..

Comment: Now my try catch in a class...this catch exception i want to dispaly in my form label..

Answer (score 2):

All variables created between the `{ }` symbols are inside the scope of the symbols themselves.

If you need to use `data` outside of it, declare it before the try.

```
string data = string.Empty; // or initialize the value to "0" if that's the default you want.

try
{
   // Don't declare data here or it won't be visible outside the try block.
   // You can set the "0" or whatever value you want here though.
   ...
}

catch (Exception Ex)
{
   ...
}

return data;
```

Answer (score 0):

The scoping of your variable `data` is only inside the Try/Catch block because you defined in it.

Try to define the variable `data` outsiude the block.